# Newrelic is not enable for sails app

Tags: node.js, sails.js, newrelic

I have integrated newrelic module with my sails app by following steps :-

1. Install newrelic module via npm install newrelic for the application.
2. Copy newrelic.js from node_modules/newrelic into the root directory of my application.
3. Edit newrelic.js and replace license_key's value with the license key for my account.
4. Add require('newrelic'); as the first line of the app.js.

While starting my app New Relic should start up with it and start reporting data but it is logging following lines in newrelic_agent.log

{"v":0,"level":30,"name":"newrelic","hostname":"xyz.net","pid":16074,"time":"2016-10-21T12:32:06.788Z","msg":"Using New Relic for Node.js. Agent version: 1.32.0; Node version: v0.12.12."}

{"v":0,"level":30,"name":"newrelic","hostname":"xyz.net","pid":16074,"time":"2016-10-21T12:32:06.792Z","msg":"Module not enabled in configuration; not starting."}

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Sails-hook-newrelic (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-newrelic) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. We have set variable NEW_RELIC_ENABLED as FALSE for dev servers initially for temporarily disabling the agent while debugging other issues.